# convert sql query to criteria api

Tags: mysql

how can i write this sql query with criteria api

SELECT `matricule`,sum(`presence_badge_minutes`),SUM(`presence_theorique_minutes`), (SELECT SUM(`presence_badge_minutes`) from presence as `t2` where ((`date_effet` BETWEEN '2016-5-20' and '2016-6-2') and(`t2`.`matricule`=`t1`.`matricule`))) as pb1,(SELECT SUM(`presence_theorique_minutes`) from presence as `t2` where ((`date_effet` BETWEEN '2016-5-20' and '2016-6-2') and(`t2`.`matricule`=`t1`.`matricule`))) as pt1, (SELECT SUM(`presence_badge_minutes`) from presence as `t2` where ((`date_effet` BETWEEN '2016-6-15' and '2016-6-20') and(`t2`.`matricule`=`t1`.`matricule`))) as pb2,(SELECT SUM(`presence_theorique_minutes`) from presence as `t2` where ((`date_effet` BETWEEN '2016-6-15' and '2016-6-20') and(`t2`.`matricule`=`t1`.`matricule`))) as pt2 from `presence` as `t1` group by `matricule`

Comment: Could you care to share what you've tried?  When you mention Criteria API, are you referring to the JPA Criteria API or specifically Hibernate's deprecated Criteria API?

Comment: this is one of my working query    :      criteriaQuery.multiselect(presenceRoot.get("Matricule"), presenceRoot.get("Nom"), presenceRoot.get("Section"), presenceRoot.get("Nom_Section"),    criteriaBuilder.sum(presenceRoot.get("Presence_Badge_minutes")), criteriaBuilder.sum(presenceRoot.get("Presence_theorique_minutes")))
    .groupBy(presenceRoot.get("Matricule"));

Comment: hibernate criteria API

Comment: The one which you say works is the JPA Criteria API and not the Hibernate Criteria API :)

Comment: i did it with  native sql and it work now because i found it too complicate to do it with criteria and  yes it's jpa criteria sorry my mistake